# /usr/local/bin/gfortran: Command not found

Tags: compiling, make

I'm getting the an error `/usr/local/bin/gfortran: Command not found` when I go to the source directory and put the command make like shown below.

```
~/Desktop/someprogram/source$ make
```

Please help with this.

```
****/usr/local/bin/gfortran -c -O2 Mad_He.f90
make: /usr/local/bin/gfortran: Command not found
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Mad_He.o' failed
make: *** [Mad_He.o] Error 127****
```

Comment: You might want to try `sudo apt-get install gfortran`, and  then run `make` again. It would be helpful to know what software you were trying to build.

Comment: My guess is that it's a rather specialist program used for thermochronology, solving a sold-state diffusion equation for Helium in Apatite, and that that information is _no use whatsoever_ in addressing the lack of a Fortran90 compiler on the system.

Comment: @JdeBP , Correct. I'm new to this program Pecube (downloaded from HUGG-Repository) and having trouble with the compilation. I have a fortran95 compiler in my system. I have checked for the dependencies and I downloaded them, but I still can't make it work. I am guessing something is wrong with the path name, maybe? Do you have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Thanks all, it seems that I have a fix. I found that the makefile contained in the source folder of the tar file had a different target path -> usr/local/bin/gfortran whereas gfortran on my Ubuntu was located in -> usr/bin/gfortran. So I just deleted the "local/" in the makefile and the program worked perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all, it seems that I have a fix. I found that the makefile contained in the source folder of the tar file had a different target path

-> usr/local/bin/gfortran

whereas gfortran on my Ubuntu was located in

-> usr/bin/gfortran

So I just deleted the "local/" in the makefile and the program worked perfect!